# When inserting the varchar value into the datetime field, it throws conversion error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: Insert execution block]

`FROM_DATE` column is `DATETIME` format in the `temptable1stockdetails` table.

`Gradd19` column is `VARCHAR` format in the `GradedDETAILS` table.

I want to insert the `Gradd19` value to `FROM_DATE` but it throws the following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated

How can I solve this issue.

Sample data of the `Gradd19` in the `GradedDETAILS` table is:

```
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM 
Sep 19 2016 12:00AM 
Sep 19 2016 12:00AM 
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM 
20 
60 
20-09-2016 
20-09-2016
```

Comment: Can you share the sample data of `Gradd19` value ?

Comment: sample data of gradd19 column.......                                                  Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 19 2016 12:00AM
20-09-2016
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 20 2016 12:00AM

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not shared the sample data of the `Gradd19` value, I suspect the date value is in the `yyyy-dd-mm` format, so when trying to convert (month value more than 12) it cause the out-of-range value error.

For sample, if the date format in `yyyy-mm-dd`, it will execute properly:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @Gradd19 AS VARCHAR (20) = '2016-11-15';
SELECT @FromDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Gradd19, 105);
SELECT @FromDate;
```

Incase if it is in `yyyy-dd-mm` it will throw out-of-range value error

```
DECLARE @FromDate1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @Gradd191 AS VARCHAR (20) = '2016-15-11';
SELECT @FromDate1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Gradd191, 105); 
SELECT @FromDate1;
```

So in that case you need do one more conversion to skip the issue, like the below:

```
DECLARE @FromDate2 DATETIME;
DECLARE @Gradd192 AS VARCHAR (20) = '2016-15-11';
SELECT @FromDate2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, @Gradd192, 105), 120)
SELECT @FromDate2;
```

---

So instead of

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, Gradd19, 105) AS ExpiryDate
```

you need to use

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, Gradd19, 105), 120) AS ExpiryDate
```

---

**Update:** As you mentioned in the comments the `Gradd19` having the values of `20` and `60`, it is difficult to filter those non-valid data. But based on the [`LEN()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190329.aspx) function you may avoid the non-valid data, then using the CONVERT you can get the VARCAHR field as DATETIME value.

Based on your sample data the valid date's minimum length is 10 characters, so you can apply the condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Sample execution:

```
DECLARE @GradedDETAILS  TABLE (Gradd19 VARCHAR (30));

INSERT INTO @GradedDETAILS (Gradd19) VALUES
('Sep 16 2016 12:00AM'),
('Sep 16 2016 12:00AM'),
('Sep 16 2016 12:00AM'), 
('Sep 19 2016 12:00AM'), 
('Sep 19 2016 12:00AM'), 
('Sep 16 2016 12:00AM'), 
('20'), 
('60'), 
('20-09-2016'), 
('20-09-2016');

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, Gradd19, 105), 120)
FROM @GradedDETAILS
WHERE LEN(Gradd19) >= 10
```

So in your actual query also you need to add the `LEN(Gradd19) >= 10` condition and in the `SELECT` use this to convert as `DATETIME` by `CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, Gradd19, 105), 120)`

Comment: Gradd19 sample data                                                                         Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
Sep 19 2016 12:00AM
Sep 19 2016 12:00AM
Sep 16 2016 12:00AM
20
60
20-09-2016
20-09-2016

Comment: Is it `Gradd19` column contain `20`, `60` also one of the value ?

Comment: ya...20 and 60 also values of gradd19 column

Comment: @user106763 Please check **`Update:`** block in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but - `DateTime` does not support anything less than '1753-01-01'.  Values less than this will generate the error you're seeing.  You might need to apply a `CASE` expression to evaluate that condition and force '1753-01-01' (or `NULL` depending on your situation) if the original value is less.

Example:

```
CASE 
    WHEN <TableColumn> < '1753-01-01' THEN '1753-01-01' 
    ELSE <TableColumn> 
END AS <TableColumn>
```